# What command do I use to find physical disk size?

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage, remote

I use `df -h` to see formatted size, but how to see actual?

I believe one of my disks is 3TB but formatted as 2TB but not sure which. (they're remote so I can't look!)

Answer (score 32):

You can try `lsblk`.

That should list all disks including size. It will also list partitions and mount points.

Comment: I don't have that cmd loaded - is there another or do I have to get that

Comment: Strange. Both my 13.04 and 12.04 installations have it. Are you sure it's a Ubuntu box?

Answer (score 3):

You could try parted

```
sudo parted -l
```

or if you know the particular disk's block device e.g. /dev/sda

```
sudo parted /dev/sda print
```

As well as looking at the formatted partition size(s), take note of the 'Partition Table' line - if the disk was formatted with 'Partition Table: msdos' then you may be bumping up against the intrinsic 2TB limit - the disc may need to be converted to a GPT partition table in order to access the full 3TB

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following command:

> sudo hdparm  -I /dev/your_device |grep GB

Change your_device with a the device name (sda, sdb, etc)